# How to see all incoming reviews in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Our organization has recently moved to gerrit.

I will be having many incoming code reviews for which i will be getting email alerts, i will not be able to review them immediately as i will be busy in some other development task

Currently i will check the mails and click on the link provided which is a cumbersome process

Is there a way in gerrit to see all the incomming reviews on clicking a link or a search query which gives all incomming reviews

I am aware of My -> Changes link

but that only shows the changes that have been done in code not the first time commits

Comment: What do you mean with "the changes that have been done in code not the first time commits"

Comment: What i mean is, if some one commits the code for first time and adds me as reviewer then that commit will not be visible in My --> Changes link. However if i have suggested some changes and the original commiter  ammends the code, did the changes and commit the code once again then if i go to My --> Changes link the code is visible

Answer (score 1):

The "Incoming reviews" section of the My -> Changes link is the answer for your question, but you can also search for "status:open reviewer:self" to see all opened changes that you were added as a reviewer.

Comment: I am aware of My -->changes link as i  have mentioned in the question, However i am not able to see the code commited for the first time by users who have added me as a reviewer at this place. However if they ammend last commit, make some change and commit once again i am able to see their code in the My-->changes link

Comment: The way you have described is not the way things must work on Gerrit. You must be able to see the changes you were added as a reviewer in the My > Changes link as soon as you were added.

Comment: Unless the change were merged / abandoned before your review

Comment: @Bustikiller, if "the change were merged/abandoned" it would be not possible to "ammend last commit".